# jquery grep in autofilter

Tags: jquery

Can jquery grep be used with an array such as

```
   var Categories= [{label:"cat1", value:"1"}, ... ]
```

in an autofilter for example

```
 $(function() {
      a = $('#Cats').autocomplete({
          source: function(req, response) {
              var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
              var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
              response($.grep(Categories, function(item) {
                  return matcher.test(item);
              }));
          },
          minLength: 0, autoFocus: true

       ,
          select: function(event, ui) {
              AutoCompleteSelectionHandler2(event, ui)
          }

      });
  });
```

So that it filters on label and returns value?

I tried various permutations of 
response($.grep(Categories, function(item) {
                  return matcher.test(item);

I can only get it to work with array

```
 var Categories= [ "cat1", "cat2", ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `item` is an object and not a string. Try with

```
return matcher.test(item.label);
```

Comment: @Lill Lansey: could you define "Didn't work"? Do you get a js error? Returns all elements? Returns no element? etc :)